# POST request in angular returning 401 token invalidate

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I need help with understanding and implementing how to add a product to my cart when clicking a button. In my example I have a list of products that I get from an API and each product has a + and - button to increase its quantity and on first click on + button to add it to cart...

I want to achieve that on the click of + button a post request happens to my API that then adds this product to my cart. My API call also check and updates the price if there has been a price change.

Now I have created a cart.service file where I added the bellow code but I keep getting a 401 error (

```
{status: 401, message: "token_invalidate"}
message: "token_invalidate"
status: 401
```

) in console on button click... What is my mistake here?

**cart.service.ts file:**

```
  addUpdateProductToCart(quantity: number, produkt: Product) {
    return from(Preferences.get({ key: 'TOKEN_KEY' })).pipe(
      switchMap(token => {
        const headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Authorization', `Bearer ${token.value}`);
        // Initialize Params Object
        let params = new HttpParams();
        // Begin assigning parameters
        params = params.append('product', produkt.id);
        params = params.append('quantity', quantity);
        return this.httpClient.post(`${environment.apiUrl}cart`, { headers, observe: 'response' }, {params});
      }),
      catchError(err => {
        console.log(err.status);
        if (err.status === 400) {
          console.log(err.error.message);
        }
        if (err.status === 401) {
          // this.authService.logout();
          // this.router.navigateByUrl('/login', { replaceUrl: true });
        }
        return EMPTY;
      }),
    );
  };
```

and this is how I'm triggering this POST request in the page where the products are listed **(subcategory.page.ts):**

```
  incrementQty(index: number, produkt: Product) {
   
    const newQty = this.products[index].step += 1.00;

    this.cartService.addUpdateProductToCart(newQty, produkt).subscribe(
        data => {
          console.log(data);
        },
        error => {
          console.log('Error', error);
        }
        );
  }
```

And the html code:

```
<ion-label>
  <div class="d-flex ion-justify-content-between">
     <div class="prod-details-wrapper">
                      <p class="product-id">{{ produkt.product_code }}</p>
                      <p class="product-em">EM: {{ produkt.unit }}</p>
                      <p class="product-packaging">Pakiranje: {{ produkt.min_weight }} {{ produkt.unit }}</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="qty-input-wrapper">
                      <ion-item lines="none" slot="end">
                        <ion-icon color="vigros" name="remove-circle" (click)="decrementQty(i, produkt)"></ion-icon>
                        <ion-input type="number" value="0" min="0" step="1" [(ngModel)]="produkt.step"></ion-input>
                        <ion-icon color="vigros" name="add-circle" (click)="incrementQty(i, produkt)"></ion-icon>
                      </ion-item>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </ion-label>
```

[image: Sample of a listed product with + and - button]

Comment: The post request expects a body in the second position. `this.httpClient.post(url, body, options)`. If there is no body to pass, then pass `null`. Take a look to the official [documentation](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient#post).

Comment: Im verry new to Angular... could you provide an example please?... I dont understand what I have to pass as body

Comment: Change the line `return this.httpClient.post(environment.apiUrl + 'cart', { headers, observe: 'response' }, {params});` to `return this.httpClient.post(environment.apiUrl + 'cart', null, { headers, observe: 'response', params });`. Your template string `${environment.apiUrl}cart` is perfectly fine, i just changed it for formatting purposes.

Comment: This seems to work :) but now I'm getting error 400 that says I have to add quantity... even tho the quantity sent is 1

Comment: Try just to `append` the params and not to reassign them like this: `// Begin assigning parameters params.append('product', produkt.id); params.append('quantity', quantity);` and check the request url in the browser devtool.

Comment: @riorudo Now the response is please select a prodct

Comment: could the be an issue with the code in the file subcategory.page.ts in the incrementQty function?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251209/discussion-between-riorudo-and-weinde).

Answer (score 1):

Post needs a body doesn't matter if its empty or not.

if you use Visual Code you can hover over Methods to see what parameters are necessary and in what order. ! or ? after a Parameter doesnt mean you can just skip it just put it down as null or undefined.

-> post(url, body, headers, params)

The way you add your token should work. Are you 100% sure you have a valid token?

If not put console.log(token) after you receive it and try the request with postman/swagger and see if you still get a 401 error.

Also if its your API just debug it and find out at what point the Authorization fails.

Comment: Yes the token is valid... the same function works with get method for getting categories and products...

Comment: Then swap your body and header like @riorudo suggested then everything should work, also you don't have to use "{params}" just use "params"

Comment: If you use visual code you can usually hover over functions and see what parameters are necessary and in what order.

Comment: how do I add data to body?

Comment: You can pass anything if its a login {username, password} works or you can initialize an object let obj = {username, password} and pass obj as the body.